# Option to remove Control M not available in Eclipse version 2020-12 (4.18.0)

Tags: eclipse, file-encodings

I am trying to use the option "File-->Convert Line Delimiters To-->Unix" in the Eclipse

Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)
Build id: 20201210-1552

But it does not seem to have it anymore. It use to always be there and is still there in the Spring Tool Suite 4 just below Refresh under the File menu.

How can one now achieve what that option use to do, in the new Eclipse.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In 2021-03, the function is right where you describe in the menu.  Even if for some reason it's not in the menu, you can probably find the function in the "Keys" tab in Preferences. You could bind the function to a key sequence so you can access it.

Comment: Possibly you have this Action Set turned off in your current perspective. Look at the "Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective" dialog, check the "Convert Line Delimiters" entry on the Action Set Availability page. and the Menu Visibility page also.

Comment: @greg-449 , Thanks, but for some reason in the 2020-12 version this option is just not showing up, I have tried both resetting the Java perspective, and removing and adding this Menu Visibility on the Java perspective. I have even restarted by 2020-12 Eclipse but the menu just does not show up.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr, thanks I had to resort to setting a keyboard shortcut and using that shortcut as I cannot get the menu to show up in Eclipse 2020-12 version.